# OpenGL ES 2.0: Converting GL_TRIANGLES into GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I **export my 3D geometry** from a 3D authoring application. It is possible to export the vertex coordinates as full triangle arrays.

On ther other hand, **triangle strips are more efficient** for the OpengGL to render. This is especially true for OpenGL ES, which is very sensitive for performance.

**Is it therefore possible to convert GL_TRIANGLES arrays into GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, please?**

Could anybody provide me with working algorithm? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you may have an answer here: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/456455-convert-triangle-list-to-triangle-strip/

Comment: +1 for good link. Hi Byte, thanks for this link. To my surprise, many people in that thread concluded that using triangle strips is much less performance efficient than triangle lists. It is not worth of implementing them because of small memory savings.

Comment: Makes the job that much easier then!